# Monerod - monero Daemon Manager - Monero wallet hangs debian

Tags: monerod, daemon

Noticed that monerod daemon hangs debian systems !!  Is there a notice or warning to run only run monero wallets in a segregated VM ? Rarely experience a complete system hang so im bringing this issue to stackexchange reddit users attn. for those who are paranoid or just EXTRA CAREFUL.

Systems:
Debian 9 LTS
Debain 4.9 - i686 GNU/Linux

Monero version: monero-gui-linux-x86-v0.11.1.0 & cli included in this tar file - BOTH CRASH/HANG DEBIAN.  tar file sha256 sum & pgp checked as advised
Riccardo "fluffypony" Spagni
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iQEzBAEBCAAdFiEElLc43TUBMvWsvuodVUMt8xzNT80FAln5m4UACgkQVUMt8xzN
T83FFAgAqiGND6bA2R9JrOH3fWIL8178TT2MF4dGHt0s9TfQZ6ZRoU6C6BWZ8MSs
wrB7yJfePCahXPLJP8VapkxvkhIwalg77lgL1130gwxdfv4XKUAmsJPFIiqDirwR
v/yJIhZJJJ9BF/DZLbVvl3yefd+Zz/jr0DPyEs7NlD1Q6K3Gv/nPBTrQlcbIq1S2
Zqz9ZG3YM0XXwbEpukfTSK0e9P6emgMr0jLu61qzoubblOEF12+Tm/HakVt0kDk4
wGEJSMv2zEPb//fg68xOpNF+9QU71IvHmjf38ZjbJdpC3GTFgO/EPa/i0EVPdN1u
F/lAiazu+JGodmhzUxeXBPMdmrZE7g==
=vZ6k
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

once monerod and monero wallet (cli or gui) close then  system unhangs.  So far have not needed to kill -9 monerod but i can imagine thats not far away if the wallet is crashing systems

Comment: Use that guide ^

Comment: seems to improve startup speed- testing now to see if it improves functionality at all.  and if it improves shutdown speed